# Eth0 recognized by ifconfig -a, interfaces correct, cannot connect?

Tags: debian, ethernet, internet, router, ifconfig

So, I had a WiFi connection "working" with WPA Supplicant. That took quite a bit of doing, and wasn't optimal. The networks would drop out every few minutes. I wrote a script which would reset the connection, but I still had 20 seconds of downtime every few minutes.

I had a spare router lying around, so I flashed the firmware to DD-WRT and configured it as a repeater bridge. I know this is working because I have successfully connected to the internet with it both wirelessly and through the ethernet ports.

I did something stupid and deleted WPA Supplicant before I even connected with the wired connection. I then changed my /etc/network/interfaces file to reflect the new settings.

I've tried several configurations in the interfaces file, but the current one is...

```
auto eth0
     iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Suffice to say I cannot acquire a connection. I then ran `ifconfig`. The result showed only the `lo`. I then ran `ifconfig -a` and saw `eth0`.

Thinking it was a driver problem, I downloaded the 82562Ez Intel LAN drivers. I unzipped the tar-ball and attempted an install. The drivers would not install because they were intended for 2.x.x kernels, while mine is 3.16.0. (I'm currently running Debian Jessie.)

I then tried multiple interface configurations. I cannot get anything to work.

I see an entry when running `lspci` for...

```
Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82562EZ 10/100 Ethernet Controller (rev 01)
```

I'm fairly new to Linux, especially command line Linux, so if I need to provide more information I would be happy to.

What could the problem be? How do I connect to my network?

**EDIT**

Using `lsmod` I found a module named `e100`. Running `modinfo e100` I found that it was indeed the Intel driver for my onboard ethernet port.

Comment: What happens if you do `dhclient eth0` and then `echo $?` ?

Comment: @schaiba It prints out "0".

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem and the solution. WPA_Supplicant was getting greedy with my network configuration even after deleting it's configuration file and changing the interface settings.

`sudo apt-get --purge remove wpasupplicant` and a reboot solved my problem.